# how to use navigator.getDisplayMedia with auto selecting the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
    audio: false,
    video: true
  }).then(gotMedia).catch(function(e) {
    console.log('getDisplayMedia() error: ', e);
  });
```

Will cause a pop up like  this

[image]

I can see in another question that using `--auto-select-desktop-capture-source` in a headless browser can fix the issue but how can implement it in the JavaScript section? I wish the screen capture automatically starts from the current tab without any popups to select which tab.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to auto-select a specific screen in Chrome media picker but I'd recommend you use the new `displaySurface` option to pre-select the pane you want (tab, window, screen).  See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/screen-sharing-controls/#displaySurface

```js
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
  // Pre-select the "Entire Screen" pane in the media picker.
  video: { displaySurface: "monitor" },
});
```

[image]